# How to search an array element in SurrealDB

Tags: surrealdb

I'm trying to perform a query that evaluates if an array includes or contains a specif value or set of values.

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE data = ['value_a']

https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/select

I've read the documentation and try several queries, but I didn't find any function or way to create this query.

I've read the official documentation and performed several queries based on the examples, but nothing have worked.

https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/select

My expected behaviour is:

Matches a specific value or set of values like these examples in SQL relational database.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 5):

There is a CONTAINS operator :
https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/operators#contains

The Query should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data CONTAINS 'value_a'
```

Comment: Thanks, Fabian, it worked really well to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have records in SurrealDB lookslike this:

```
[
    {
        email: 'jan@test3.co.za',
        firstname: 'Jan',
        id: person:0b3b952c565155fcb0ae9acfedf99315,
        lastname: 'Brand',
        program: [
            'flights',
            'apps'
        ]
    },
    {
        email: 'sam@test3.co.za',
        firstname: 'Sam',
        id: person:8bc35665018b595b95bd9b2e909ed651,
        lastname: 'pedlar',
        program: [
            'entertainment'
        ]
    }
]
```

You want to select the record where the 'program' array contains the value 'apps', then you can use the following statement:

```
select * from person where program contains 'apps';
```

You will then get the following answer:

```
{
    email: 'jan@test3.co.za',
    firstname: 'Jan',
    id: person:0b3b952c565155fcb0ae9acfedf99315,
    lastname: 'Brand',
    program: [
        'flights',
        'apps'
    ]
}
```